# remove single use html italic/bold wrapper - leave is multiple html styles are used

Tags: php, domdocument

Every so often a member at one of my websites will post a message where the entire message is wrapped with an italic bold style commend.

We allow both plus most other html styles.

But, it is kind of annoying when a person posts their entire message in italic or bold.

So been pondering on this but no really good ideas.

It would have to check to see if:

(1) any font style has been used

(2) if a font style has been used:

(a) are there multiple font styles being used, if so, ignore processing

(b) if the font style does not wrap the entire block of content, ignore processing

(c) if the font style DOES wrap the entire block of content, process the removal.

(d) If the entire block of content is wrapped, and other html code exists (urls, blockquotes, etc) only remove the style formatting.

I am sure I might be missing a step or such in there, but hopefully this gives everybody an idea of what I am after.

Comment: The answer you seek requires examples of what you are trying to and trying not to filter. And the answer will probably be in the form of a regular expression.

Comment: It looks like you're after someone else writing your code. Look at `preg_match` and `regex` that might help. http://us3.php.net/preg_match